# The Reserved IP is currently in use

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-cloud-services

I have deployed a Azure cloud service with reserved IP using following configuration:

```
  <InstanceAddress roleName="WorkerRole">
    <Subnets>
      <Subnet name="default" />
    </Subnets>
  </InstanceAddress>
  <ReservedIPs>
    <ReservedIP name="MyReservedIP" />
  </ReservedIPs>
```

But when I'm trying to update this deployment and deploying to staging slot, I'am getting following:

Error: The Reserved IP MyReservedIP is currently in use by Deployment xxxxx belonging to HostedService xxxxx.  Http Status Code: BadRequest  OperationId:xxxx

Answer (score 3):

Apparently when deploying to a staging slot you need to use a different reserved ip name. For instance:

- Production worker has ReservedIp "ReservedIpProd"
- Staging worker has ReservedIp "ReservedIpStaging"

When you deploy to staging the IP in use will be the staging IP. When you then swap staging to production the codebase will be changed but the reserved IPs stay attached to the slots they were originally assigned to.

For instance:

- VIP swap staging to production
- Your production deployment (which was previously staging) retains "RevervedIpProd"
- Your staging environment (which was previously production) retains "ReservedIpStaging"

See the second comment [here on the Azure Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role/suggestions/7845213-make-reserved-ip-support-production-and-staging-sl)

I would suggest you try it this way and verify whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

A comment to the name of the reserved IPs:

You must use exactly the same name which is shown by the PowerShell command Get-AzureReservedIP in the first line of every result which is named "ReservedIPName". First use Add-AzureAccount to log in into your Azure account in PowerShell.

For example in my case it is a concatenation of the Resource group ("abc") and the name of the reserved IP ("defIP"). => "Group abc defIP"

ServiceConfiguration.myService.cscfg:

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="mysvc" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="5" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
...
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
        <ReservedIP name="Group abc defIP" />
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```